# Load Script as a text in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, uiwebview

I am having a webview in which I need to load some `html text`. But now my problem is when some one enter some script like this

```
foo<script>alert('omg hacked')</script>bar<br>
```

at that time its giving an alert while loading html. [image]

How to avoid this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the xmp tag to ingore `script` execution. Like bellow

```
yourHtml = [yourHtml stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<script>" withString:@"<xmp style='display:inline'><script>"];
yourHtml = [yourHtml stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</script>" withString:@"</script></xmp>"];
```